# Adding Text before pagination link segment of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, uri, segments

hi i just want to ask about codeigniter pagination link.

this my controller :

```
    $configp['base_url'] = base_url().'post';
    $configp['total_rows'] = $this->db->where('status',0)->get('room_post')->num_rows();
    $configp['per_page'] =5;
    $configp['uri_segment'] = 2;

    $this->pagination->initialize($configp);

    $data['pendinglink'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

i want to add text before the segment of pagination example if i create this link it will generate this link

```
<strong>1</strong>
<a href="http://localhost/istay/post/5" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a>
<a href="http://localhost/istay/post/5" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="next">&gt;</a>
```

i want to add "pendingpost" before "5" of "http://localhost/istay/post/5" so it will have a result of "http://localhost/istay/post/pendingpost/5"

i search about it and i find out about "config['first_url']" but i don't fully understand it and i think it will only modify first url of the link. i hope someone can help. thx.

Comment: You can use `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
$configp['base_url'] = base_url().'post';
```

to

```
$configp['base_url'] = base_url().'post/pendingpost';
```

Comment: haha i didn't realize that. haha thank you for your answer. :)